# I use the rdpsign that comes with windows to sign the rdp file I saved, I still haven't solved it, but it reports an error

Tags: windows, rdp

I'm sorry I'm posting again because this problem I'm having is still not resolved and there is no sir to answer it for me

`rdpsign.exe .\rdp_1.rdp /sha256 669f898eb66b3a309ca554198b643f014a6e4b6e`
I use this piece of command in powershell and it works. I opened the RDP file I saved on the RDP server without reporting an error, but when I put it on my other machine, an error occurred.

I tried running an RDP file without a signature and it opened. It can be opened normally on the RDP server or other devices

I also checked Microsoft's official documentation to confirm that the syntax is correct. I don’t know why, after signing the RDP file, it can be accessed normally in the RDP service, but the RDP file is damaged on other machines

I also tried to delete these two fields in the rdp file, still the same

```
rdgiskdcproxy
kdcproxyname
```

By the way, when I tested the RDP file, I created a dedicated user to connect to the RDP service. I used the administrator role on the RDP server for remote vacant access when configuring and testing, so I used RDP in the RDP service for testing, and there was no conflict.RDP server is WinSrv2022, other machines are Win10

I also looked at similar situation of other people in stackoverflow forum, I also tried to change RDP file, it still not solve

Comment: Did you find the answer to this? I am experiencing the same issue.